# Can I book a second flight on the same day with the same airline without cancelling my first flight?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I want to cancel a return flight with Ethiopian airlines. It is a two leg flight and I want to go to a different final destination. I am then going to book a new flight for the same day which has the same first leg as the cancelled one but a different second leg.

Will I have any problems checking in if I do or do not cancel the first two-leg flight?

Comment: Anecdote: I did a similar thing, rebooking the first of a two-leg flight with Ethiopian (changing departure but going to the same destination). Contacting the airline and asking them to rebook worked fine (and was slightly cheaper than buying a new ticket).

Answer (score 14):

There may be some confusion at check-in about which ticket you are using, but as long as you have the ticket record (PNR) on hand to indicate which one you want to use, **you should be fine**.

However, are you sure purchasing an entirely new ticket is the best option?  It's worth contacting the airline and seeing if they can just change your final destination: while there will probably be change fees involved, this is likely to be cheaper than booking a new flight.

Even if you have a completely nonchangeable/nonrefundable ticket, it's worth canceling the old one, since this way you can at least claim back the taxes and fees.

Comment: This is new but interesting info to me: can you get taxes and fees refunded if you cancel a non-refundable ticket? How?

Comment: @user Yes, you can, call the airline and ask.